# Assignto a global variable using an alias in foreach loop (php)

Tags: php

I am trying to reassign a global variable (in this case '$aDoor') by doing ($checkbox = $data;) on line 8. Not sure how to solve this and would love some help!

```
$checkboxes = array($aDoor,$bro);

foreach ($checkboxes as $checkbox => $checkdata) {
    $data = '';
    foreach ($checkdata as $check) {
        $data .= $check . ", ";
    }
    $checkbox = $data;
    echo $data;
}
echo $aDoor;
```

Comment: Worth to mention: Avoid using global variables.

Comment: What's your question or what's not working and should be solved?

Comment: I need to set $data to $aDoor and $bro after the foreach loop has done its work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to work by reference. Throw in some ampersands:

```
$aDoor = array("hi", "hi2");
$bro = array("bye", "bye2");
$checkboxes = array(&$aDoor, &$bro);
//& means modifications to $checkbox[0] will also change $aDoor
//vs. just making a copy of $aDoor

foreach ($checkboxes as &$checkbox) { //same here
    $checkbox = implode(",", $checkbox);
}
print($aDoor);
```

Also, implode is a far simpler method of joining together an array.

Comment: That didn't work for me, $aDoor still does not resolve to $data. I tried prepending the ampersand before $checkbox but that gave me a 500 error.

Comment: Sorry, must've been halfway through updating the code. Try that: it's much simpler and should do the job :)